# How to make a network request in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, httprequest

This is a rather simple question. How do I make a network request using VB.NET? I'm not talking anything complicated, just sending a request to a web server and receiving a response of any kind. I would normally use a php background process, but I wanted to know what the pure VB version of this would be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Public Function IsConnectionAvailable() As Boolean
    Dim objUrl As New System.Uri("http://www.google.co.id")
    Dim objWebReq As System.Net.WebRequest
    objWebReq = System.Net.WebRequest.Create(objUrl)
    Dim objresp As System.Net.WebResponse

    Try
        objresp = objWebReq.GetResponse
        objresp.Close()
        objresp = Nothing
        Return True

    Catch ex As Exception
        objresp = Nothing
        objWebReq = Nothing
        Return False
    End Try
End Function
```

And for the call

```
Public Sub getConnectionApllication()
    If IsConnectionAvailable() = True Then
        MsgBox("Connected")
    Else
        MsgBox("Not Connected")
    End If
End Sub
```